# Where does OneNote for Mac store its notebook files?

Tags: macos, library, microsoft, hacking, onenote

"Create a new notebook" with OneNote for Mac is not possible in offline mode. :(
Editing and updating your notebook, however, works flawlessly in offline mode.

My question is: where does OneNote for Mac store its Notebook files (for offline work)?

Also, I would love to find a workaround to use OneNote in offline mode and to block sync in my firewall.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OneNote stores things in an application container in your user's Library folder. Open Finder and use the go to folder function and paste

```
~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.onenote.mac/Data/Library/Application Support/Microsoft User Data/OneNote/
```

The current version has an offline data file in a 15.0 subfolder. You can snoop on the program when it's running to see what files and ports are open.

```
sudo lsof | grep OneNote | grep -v Applications
```

Answer (score 2):

I dug down into the folder you're talking about bmike.  The most interesting folder appeared to be OneNoteOfflineCache_Files, but when I tapped on each of the .onebin files, they appear to be just graphics files representing menus and such that you see when you're in OneNote.

The only other folder with something in it was ServerListings and that has a single .onesrvcache file that doesn't look like it has data in it either.

then I took a look at OneNoteOfflineCache.onecache using TextWrangler. It's full of unreadable glop but then I found a section in actual English talking about taxonomy of polar bears!  Emboldened I did a search for a term I'd used in a notebook and sure enough my data was in there.  Oddly not everything I wrote in my note was searchable, just some terms.

Fun stuff - not terribly useful if you're thinking you can get to that data without OneNote, but still fun in a geeky kind of way.  I did find a $20 (Normally $40) application called Outline that says it will open OneNote files though: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/outline/id604802021?mt=12

Comment: Great post and answers thanks.  So, if I want to include my OneNote content in a local or cloud backup process (e.g. idrive.com) should I add this folder?  Or is it a waste of time (since presumably OneNote is already storing my data in the cloud and even if it wasn't I couldn't recreate my ONeNote content from these cache files).

Comment: I wonder how Outline has managed to open the files. I cannot google any file format documentation for OneNote, nor official or unofficial. Did the guys do some hardcore reverse engineering :)?